# Cannot install any updates on clean Windows 8.1

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I made a clean install of Windows 8.1 on a computer. I'm trying to check for updates. The update check takes very long and finally the Windows Update section tells me that no updates are available and that no check has ever been done.

Why does the update check fail? What can I do with it?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/922261/windows-8-1-stuck-on-checking-for-updates and https://superuser.com/questions/1103966/windows-update-doesnt-work-on-window-8-1 and https://superuser.com/questions/1189623/how-to-fix-windows-8-1-update-hanging and https://superuser.com/questions/1396051/windows-update-problems-after-fresh-windows-8-1-install and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/windows-8-update-searches-forever-solved/71976680-ccc5-4bd6-bfe5-f2f46ae7c734

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 stuck on "Checking for updates..."](https://superuser.com/questions/922261/windows-8-1-stuck-on-checking-for-updates)

Comment: I had no luck with the existing answers, including the accepted answer. I did however persist and did eventually find a working solution which I have posted below. Perhaps this should become the accepted answer, as it seems to be more up to date.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Stop the Windows Update Service (via [services.msc](http://computerstepbystep.com/windows_update_service.html) or in a cmd.exe which is started as admin via `net stop wuauserv`), download and install this update:

**[Installing and searching for updates is slow and high CPU usage occurs in Windows 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102812)**

Do a reboot and check again for new updates.

Comment: I recommend using services.msc, because after running `net stop wuauserv` as admin Windows Update was still running according to services.msc

Answer (score 3):

I had this exact same problem.

You need the new version of windows update.  The problem is, the patch notes for the updates you need don't actually tell you that they update windows update.

You need KB3173424 first, then install KB3172614.  You should disconnect your computer from the network and restart before installing these after downloading.

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3173424

https://www.catalog.update.microsoft.com/Search.aspx?q=KB3172614

I don't actually know if disconnecting your computer from the network to prevent windows update launching in the backround is necessary, but it worked for me.  Similarly, I don't know if the updates must be installed in that order, or even if you need both of them.  I just know it finally made the update process work.  Hurray.

Comment: I had the same problem. Tried different combinations of Windows 8.1/Windows 8 and suggested tools. Finally using this solution helped me to get updates for Windows 8.1

Answer (score 2):

This problem continues into 2019, and, to my experience, none of the above answers are effective in the present day. At great length, I have been able to correct this issue with my Dell 3135 after a factory image restoration and installing update KB4504418 followed by KB3172614 & then KB4512488. Lots of helpful clues to be found in [this thread](https://community.norton.com/en/forums/windows-updater). I did stop the Windows Update service before applying these updates, & I did apply them using an Administrative Command terminal, entering:

```
start /wait "" "%SystemRoot%\system32\wusa.exe" "C:\full\path\to\Update.msu" /quiet /norestart
```

as described in [this very expert advice](http://wu.krelay.de/en/). (For those less savvy, you must replace the above path, "C:\full\path\to\Update.msu", with the **explicit** full path to the update module.

It is worth mentioning that I was unable to enact any of these updates in *Safe Mode* as advised in an earlier solution.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Is there an obvious easy way to check if it worked? Should the normal Windows Update work after that?

Comment: Edit: This should be the accepted answer. Automatic updates do work after exactly the steps described by Jackalope.  
Worth mentioning: the updates are only downloadable via the Microsoft Update Catalogue.

Comment: Yes, Atripes, ordinary Windows Update should finally be functional after these steps. Of course, that may change as time goes on, as it has since earlier answers were posted. Glad this worked for you.

Answer (score 0):

I used this method and it worked.

1. Run cmd as administrator.

Type the following commands:

2. `net stop wuauserv`
3. `ren SoftwareDistribution SoftwareDistribution.old`
4. `net start wuauserv`

I managed to finally install updates using the above method.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks user683780.. The process you described helped me get Windows 8.1 updating again. The only additional step I had to make was to enter safe mode in order to rename the software distribution folder.

My steps were:

- turn off auto update,
- download KBs (save),
- restart computer in safe mode,
- Rename SoftwareDistribution folder,
- restart PC,
- run the two KBs,
- restart PC and;
- return updates to auto.

Check for updates showed 223 updates pending.

Comment: Which two KBs? It would be useful to specify them explicitly

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient privileges to upvote answers you like, which is the Super User way of saying thank you

Comment: This user added additional information that makes his answer useful, & not merely a "thank you".

Comment: @Greenonline- Edited the answer with not only names, but also links to the relevant updates.

Answer (score -1):

After a clean install of Win8.1 I had this problem.
The method outlined by user683780 (manually d/l KB3173424 and KB3172614 etc) worked for me. Be sure to disconnect your computer from the internet before running these files, otherwise they will not install - your computer will look like it is installing the first one but in fact it is still trying to use the old version of windows update already installed. As well as being disconnected from the internet before running these updates I stopped the existing windows update service on my machine (press windows key and R key, type services.msc into the run box, locate the windows update service in the list (wuauserv) and stop it). My laptop is now busy installing 1.2GB of important updates! :) PS be sure to run the updates in the order given in the answer above.

Comment: Please don't add "thanks" as answers. Invest some time in the site and you will gain sufficient [privileges](https://superuser.com/privileges) to upvote answers you like, which is the Super User way of saying thank you.