# How to fix Windows 8.1 Update Hanging

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

My Windows 8.1 laptop has not been updated for a long time. I am trying to run Windows Update > `Check for updates` but it keeps showing the `Checking for updates...` progress bar **forever** (more than 3 hours):

[image: Checking for updates...]

I tried all two approaches described in the YouTube video entitled "How To Fix Windows Stuck On Checking For Updates FIX 2017!" but none works. Namely:

1. Stop 2 services and delete all contents of the SoftwareDistribution folder.
2. Downloading from Microsoft and running the `Windows Update Troubleshooter`.

I also disabled the firewall, as suggested here:

https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows_other-windows_install/fix-windows-updates-fail-to-install-in-windows-7-8/260f8566-8d0f-4535-817a-be01c6a9d0f7

But none worked for me. Is there any other trick that I can use to revive* my laptop's Windows 8.1 update?

*I'm saying *revive* because it used to work perfectly. I don't know when it stopped.

---

**UPDATE:**

@magicandre1981's 1st tip in his answer did the trick:

[image: Windows Update works!]

(the reason it says "Never" for "Updates were installed" is because during all my attempts to revive update, I have reset and clear the entire SoftwareDistribution folder)

Comment: How long have you actually waited, as it's impossible to wait forever?

Comment: @djsmiley2k About 3 hours.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/922261/windows-8-1-stuck-on-checking-for-updates and https://superuser.com/questions/1120602/cannot-install-any-updates-on-clean-windows-8-1 and https://superuser.com/questions/1103966/windows-update-doesnt-work-on-window-8-1 and https://superuser.com/questions/1396051/windows-update-problems-after-fresh-windows-8-1-install and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/windows-8-update-searches-forever-solved/71976680-ccc5-4bd6-bfe5-f2f46ae7c734

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 stuck on "Checking for updates..."](https://superuser.com/questions/922261/windows-8-1-stuck-on-checking-for-updates)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stop the `Windows Update` Service (via [services.msc](http://computerstepbystep.com/windows_update_service.html) or in a cmd.exe which is started as admin via `net stop wuauserv` - [this improves speed of installing the MSU update](https://superuser.com/a/1044548/174557) which you have to download), download and install this update by double click on the MSU:

**[Installing and searching for updates is slow and high CPU usage occurs in Windows 8.1](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102812)**

Do a reboot and check again for new updates. Now Windows Update should work and show new updates in a few minutes. If not, stop Windows Update again and [try the March 2016 Windows Update Client](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3138615).

Comment: OMG You are an angel. Your [1st tip](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/3102812) did the trick. Thank you so much!

Comment: I was sure hoping this would work, but running either of the indicated downloads behaves a lot like Windows Update itself, in that it puts up a window saying "Searching for updates on this computer" and then sits there forever with the scrolling progress bar.  And not even the Cancel button works.

Comment: @vanmelle as I said, before clicking on the MSU , stop the WU service otherwise you get the hang.

Comment: Oh, I made sure to stop the service.  It didn't help.  I eventually succeeded with the help in [this other post](https://superuser.com/a/1409639/1020518)