# Windows update problems after fresh Windows 8.1 install

Tags: windows-8.1, windows-update

I did a fresh install of Windows and right off the bat, Windows update would hang when I had it search for updates.  It would show searching for updates and then hang on that screen.  I let it go for about an hour.  I was able to follow steps that I read on this forum to get it working but my computer has only a couple of days left on the warranty and so I would like to figure out if there is a hardware problem.

Here is what happened:

1. Windows Update would hang on the screen "checking for updates."
2. Downloaded Windows update client, which would also hang.
3. Used Reset Windows Update agent tool, which basically clears out the Windows update cache.  Then, `sfc /scannow` and `Dism /Online /Cleanup-Image /RestoreHealth`.  Ran Windows Update tool again, it installed an update, which I think is an update to the Windows Update software.
4. Computer was now able to find updates.  The status bar said that the computer was almost done installing updates.  But, at the end it gave a message saying that there was a problem installing updates.
5. Followed steps on Microsoft webpage here: 
   https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/10164/fix-windows-update-errors.
   Network troubleshooter did not find anything.
   Windows Update troubleshooter had these results:

   ```
   Service registration missing or corrupt - Fixed
   Windows Update error 0x80070003(2019-01-19-T-12_31_03A) - Fixed
   Problems installing recent updates - Fixed
   ```
6. Computer says that it needs to restart in order to apply updates.  I restart.
7. When I go to the check for updates screen again, it still says "last checked for updates: never & last installed updates: never."  But, available updates seems to reflect that some updates were installed.

Comment: Similar issue with Windows 7, not sure what should be done with W81....https://superuser.com/questions/951960/windows-7-sp1-windows-update-stuck-checking-for-updates/1022204

Comment: My post is about the WHY, not about the HOW.  Since all are installing the same software, probably has to do with computer hardware, internet connection, or something with Microsoft's server?

Comment: Why will only draw opinions.

Comment: I see what you are saying but "most likely A, B, or C." is somewhat factual.

Comment: "My post is about the WHY," always draws opinions, and no it is not a hardware problem, it is a problem using an unsupported and outdated Operating System.

Comment: @Moab - Worth pointing out that Windows 8.1 is in extended supported until Jan 10th 2023.

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/922261/windows-8-1-stuck-on-checking-for-updates and https://superuser.com/questions/1120602/cannot-install-any-updates-on-clean-windows-8-1 and https://superuser.com/questions/1103966/windows-update-doesnt-work-on-window-8-1 and https://superuser.com/questions/1189623/how-to-fix-windows-8-1-update-hanging and https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/windows8_1-update/windows-8-update-searches-forever-solved/71976680-ccc5-4bd6-bfe5-f2f46ae7c734

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Windows 8.1 stuck on "Checking for updates..."](https://superuser.com/questions/922261/windows-8-1-stuck-on-checking-for-updates)

Answer (score 0):

try installing [Zeffy's wufuc from github](https://github.com/zeffy/wufuc/releases/tag/v1.0.1.201)

In my case, it had resolved the problem and had also stopped "unsupported Hardware" pop up.